# Is it possible to recommend a local VSIX file extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vsix

Ive created a .vsix file and its included it in my workspace repository. When other developers pull the repo and open visual studio I want them to get a recommendation to install the local vsix file. I know we can do this with extensions published to the market place using:

extensions.js:

```
{
    "recommendations": [
        "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint"
    ]
}
```

Is it possible to point to a local vsix file here?